# Add item at the bottom of a drawer component

Tags: reactjs, navigation-drawer, drawer, react-navigation-drawer, react-tsx

How would I place an entry of a drawer component at the bottom?
(instead of consecutively from the top)

For example, I want the help item to be at the bottom of the drawer navigation.

[image]

Here is the code I have so far

```
     <Drawer
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
      >
        <List>
          <ListItem>
             <ListItemIcon ... </ListItemIcon>
             <ListItemIcon ... </ListItemIcon>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem>
             <ListItemIcon ... </ListItemIcon>
             <ListItemIcon ... </ListItemIcon>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem>
             <ListItemIcon ... </ListItemIcon>
             <ListItemIcon ... </ListItemIcon>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem>
             <ListItemIcon ... </ListItemIcon>
             <ListItemIcon ... </ListItemIcon>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem>
             <ListItemIcon ... </ListItemIcon>
             <ListItemIcon ... </ListItemIcon>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem>
             <ListItemIcon ... </ListItemIcon>
             <ListItemIcon ... </ListItemIcon>
          </ListItem>


          <ListItem
            style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: "0" }}
            dense
            button
            component={Link}
            to={"/help"}
          >
            <ListItemIcon>{<HelpIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={"Help"} />
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Drawer>
```

There have been some past posts about this topic but nothing related to using list components to build drawer components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution!! Create a separate list and add `style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: "0" }}` to its style prop.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest answer I can think of is adding a `margin-top: auto` (might be `marginTop` for the style prop) to the `ListItem`

Comment: unfortunately, margin-top/margin-buttom style options do not work.